# How to loading outside .love save file? (love2d+ LUA)

Tags: lua, load, fopen, love2d

I write editor and game and it requires a save game option.
I Just want use a Save folder in game folder. not inside.love

How to get a bug.

1. Start game
2. Enter menu by Escape key
3. Press save game - this create savegame
4. Press Load game - you get an error "File not exist" but you write this file seconds ago.

I successful save a game in savesm2k folder but it folder outside .love file and i don't know how correct load saved game.

Used engine: Love2d 0.10.2
OS: Linux Mint 18.1 x64bit

I read many manuals and I'm stuck.

For loading save game i use this commands

```
lsg=love.filesystem.getSaveDirectory().."/M2k-Saves/m2ksave" 
lsg=love.filesystem.getSourceBaseDirectory().."/M2k-Saves/m2ksave"; 
data, size = love.filesystem.read (lsg);
leveldatacopy=freadbin (data);
```

Why does the program not try read existing file? and report no exist? I try using another command but using GetSaveDirectory broke function WriteMAP (requires for binary map and data writing) etc. but it write files which cannot be loaded in load section.

Maybe I should use LUA for reading files direct from folder but I don't know how to correct DO it.

example with bug.
https://github.com/dj--alex/m2ktest
file    m2ktest-load-savegame-test.love

At this moment on every saving i manually replace saved game inside love archive (!) . This is not normal.

Anybody can tell me how i get and correct open saved file? Not from inside .love file . from outside of course. If levels and configs can be readed from love file inside save files must be outside. I can only can create files outside love file . i know love file is a zip archive.

If required i can post a .love file but is game completely done and have 150kb of clean code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not prefix paths with `love.filesystem.getSaveDirectory()` or `love.filesystem.getSourceBaseDirectory()`.  This is done automatically, internally to the `love.filesystem` functions.  Saying

```
lsg = "/M2k-Saves/m2ksave" 
data, size = love.filesystem.read (lsg)
leveldatacopy = freadbin (data)
```

should work, and will place the file in the save directory / outside of the .love file or game directory.  (Love forbids writing anywhere except in the save directory.)

---

Love's filesystem model is like a "stack" of filesystems.  For file reading, it first looks in `love.filesystem.getSaveDirectory()` with whatever path you pass in.  If it finds a file, it uses that; otherwise it looks inside the `love.filesystem.getSourceBaseDirectory()` (or – if packed – inside the .zip / .love file).  Writing files always goes to `love.filesystem.getSaveDirectory()`, you cannot write to `love.filesystem.getSourceBaseDirectory()` (because it may not be an actual directory but a zip file).

Comment: Unfortunately no work. Problem still here.  I already tries that:::  lsg = "/M2k-Saves/m2ksave" 
    data, size = love.filesystem.read (lsg);
error ("data:"..data); -- added check line - data = nil (!) always. 
    leveldatacopy=freadbin (data);    - bad argument #1 to gfind string expected, got nil ..

Comment: @АлексейФуфаев Have you created the parent directory, like `love.filesystem.createDirectory( "M2k-Saves" )`? If you don't, that may be the reason.

Comment: Of course it's created month ago.  http://s46.radikal.ru/i111/1706/be/413f6fe8ee82t.jpg

Comment: @АлексейФуфаев In the save directory, not the source directory. (Which – if missing – you'll probably have to do by code, so it also happens for others.)